# Is there a way to pass a Object as param to router in VueJS 3 (Composition API + script setup)?

Tags: vue.js, object, routes, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

In this project, there's the user which is a js object, like this:

```
const user = {
 "ID": id,
 "NAME": name, 
 "EMAIL": email,
 ...
}
```

And here's the router on VueJS:

```
{ 
    path: '/home/:user',
    component: Home      
},
```

But this won't work of course, it expects a String, not a Object. It would be annoying transform this URL to hold all params, like this:  path: '/home/:id/:name/:email/:etc...' because the object has lots of attributes and perhaps there'll be another objects to pass to routes.

Is there a simple way to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.stringify(user) before sending it as a parameter to the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1.Serialize the user object into a JSON string when navigating to the route:

```
const navigateToHome = () => {
  router.push({ name: 'home', params: { user: JSON.stringify(user) } })
}
```

2.Configure your router to accept the serialized user object as a parameter:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/home/:user',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    props: route => ({
      user: JSON.parse(route.params.user)
    })
  },
  // ... other routes
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

export default router
```

you might want to check the vue router link in the function mode section:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#Function-mode

Comment: This will probably solve the user object issue, but I must pass other object as well, such as socket, from socket.io which is a object I have no control.